# Excel IF statement from a list

Tags: excel, if-statement

So I have an excel document, and in a column I listing different named groups of people. To the right of that named group, I have a "Lowest Estimated Member Count" and to the right of that I have a "Highest Estimated Member Count". Now I know how to write an if statement to say IF this group's name is listed in a cell, then put a "5" in the lowest estimated column". What I would like to be able to do is instead of writing a very long IF statement with the 10 different group names and what numbers to put if that name is entered, is have a list on another book that when I enter a name in the cell, it recognizes it, and populates the lowest or highest estimated cell with the number related to that group's name.

Comment: Are you familiar with `vlookup()`? This sounds like it will do what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `vlookup` as tospig suggests. The table you wish to populate is in cols "R to T". The formula will return the value `14`, as per the value in the data in columns "V, W, X". You can tell `vlookup` which column to search when it has found the row ("group1", in this case) using the second-to-last parameter (in the formula below we are asking to return values in column 2 of the data table (which is column W)). 
[image]